# Como inserir title nos links de paginação e no button::make - Yajra Laravel Datatables

Tags: php, laravel, datatable, acessibilidade

Olá, pessoal!

Uso o Datatables para Laravel do Yajra, e preciso adaptá-lo a acessibilidade.

Infelizmente, não estou conseguindo inserir title nos Button::make e nem nos links de paginação.

Com relação ao Button::make, tentei inserir o title, assim como é feito no Column::make, porém, não funcionou...
Já a paginação, não imagino como poderia inserir o title.

Alguma ideia de como fazer isso?
Desde já agradeço a todos!

Como é feito no Column:

```
Column::make('descricao')->title('Descrição')
```

Como tentei fazer com o Button:

```
    public function html()
{
    return $this->builder()
                ->setTableId('data-table')
                ->columns($this->getColumns())
                ->minifiedAjax()
                ->dom('Bfrtip')
                ->orderBy(1, 'desc')
                ->buttons(
                    Button::make('postExcel')->text('<i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i> Excel')->title('Download planilha Excel'),
                    Button::make('postCsv')->text('<i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i> CSV'),
                    Button::make('reset')->text('Limpar'),
                )
                ->parameters([
                    "language" => [ 'url' => asset('/portuguese-brasil.json')]
                ]);
}
```

- Button::make('postExcel')->text(' Excel')**->title('Download planilha Excel')**,

1. **PHP Version:** 7.4.3
2. **Laravel Version:** 6.18.14
3. **Laravel-Datatables Version:** 1.5.0
4. Usado **Service Implementations** do Yajra Laravel Datatables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolução:

```
Button::make('postExcel')->text('<span title="Download planilha Excel"><i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i> Excel</span>')
```